# Group by age range and gender with aggregation function on some columns

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, select, group-by

In Mysql, I have a patient table with id, birth_year and gender. Next table is transactions in which I have id, patient_id [FK from patient] and checkup_date. I need to select rows such that I get number of checkups for all males and females in the range of ages.

How do I query to achieve the following tabular result ?

under 20, male: 10 times, female: 15 times

21 -  30, male: 20 times, female: 35 times

31 -  40, male: 30 times, female: 45 times

....      .......        .........      .......     ........    ..........

81 -  90, male: 10 times, female: 6 times

above 90, male : 0 times, female: 4 times

Thank you.

Comment: Search for pivot mysql.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13186519/84143) answer as well could also be of help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two options.

a) Use sub query

```
select 
  concat(10*floor(age/10), '-', 10*floor(age/10) + 10) as `range`, 
  gender, 
  count(*) as count 
from (
  select 
    *, 
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,birth_year,CURDATE()) AS age
  from 
    transaction left join patient on patient_id = patient.id
) as t group by `range`, gender;
```

Gives

```
+-------+--------+-------+
| range | gender | count |
+-------+--------+-------+
| 0-10  | m      |     2 |
| 10-20 | m      |     1 |
| 20-30 | m      |     3 |
| 30-40 | f      |     2 |
| 30-40 | m      |     2 |
| 50-60 | f      |     1 |
| 50-60 | m      |     1 |
| 60-70 | f      |     5 |
| 60-70 | m      |     3 |
| 70-80 | f      |     1 |
| 70-80 | m      |     6 |
+-------+--------+-------+
```

b) Group by age first and then group in range in application.

When using ORMs it's not easy to do sub queries, so this might be a good idea.

Performance wise: Considering that average humans live for 100 years, there can be at max 200 records (100 male and 100 female) which can be easily looped in an application.

```
select 
  gender, 
  TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,birth_year,CURDATE()) AS age,
  count(*)
from 
  transaction left join patient on patient_id = patient.id
group by age, gender
```

Gives

```
+--------+------+----------+
| gender | age  | count(*) |
+--------+------+----------+
| m      |    4 |        2 |
| m      |   14 |        1 |
| m      |   24 |        3 |
| f      |   34 |        2 |
| m      |   34 |        2 |
| f      |   54 |        1 |
| m      |   54 |        1 |
| f      |   64 |        5 |
| m      |   64 |        3 |
| f      |   74 |        1 |
| m      |   74 |        6 |
+--------+------+----------+
```

Comment: Thank you @bibstha, but I wanted both the genders: male and female in the same column. Your technique gives same age range twice for male and female patients. Any way out please?

Comment: @sangam Not sure but could be done in application level instead of database.

Comment: Thank you so much @bibstha, I finally queried how you described and for the rest, I am playing with application code now. :)

Comment: Note that this solution may show that it counts twice those that have an age in the boundaries, ie. if someone has 10 years, it would count in the 0-10 and 10-20 group.